# Save result of javascript function from web page in Excel VBA

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, web-scraping, html-table

I am coding a macro in excel for web scraping from a particular web page. I am able to go to the web page.The problem is, in that page, there is a hyperlink, which is associated with a java script function to generate a html table. I want to get the data from this table. but, this dynamically created table is not showing up in "View Source" and  I am not able to access it. I will share the Java script function here.

---

**Table:**

[image: Data]

---

**JS function generating table:**

```js
function create_table(ret,pshow){
var l_Count = ret.getElementsByTagName("td").length; 
if(l_Count>0){
var cols = ret.getElementsByTagName("th").length;   
var rows = l_Count/cols;
var tbl=document.createElement('table');
tbl.setAttribute('class','t20Report t20Standard');
tbl.style.borderCollapse="collapse";
var tbdy=document.createElement('tbody');
var tr=document.createElement('tr');
    for(var k=0;k<cols;k++){
        var th=document.createElement('th');
th.setAttribute('class','t20ReportHeader');
th.appendChild(document.createTextNode(ret.getElementsByTagName("th")[k].firstChild.nodeValue));
        tr.appendChild(th);
    }
tbdy.appendChild(tr);
var r=0;
for(var i=0;i<rows;i++){
    var tr=document.createElement('tr');
    for(var j=0;j<cols;j++){
        var td=document.createElement('td');
td.setAttribute('class','t20data');
     td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(ret.getElementsByTagName("td")[r].firstChild.nodeValue));
r++;
        tr.appendChild(td);
    }
    tbdy.appendChild(tr);
}``
tbl.appendChild(tbdy);
pshow.appendChild(tbl);
}
else
{
var t=document.createTextNode("DATA NOT AVAILABLE");
pshow.appendChild(t);
}
```

This generates a HTML code as below.

---

**HTML for the table:**

```html
<table class="t20Report t20Standard" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th class="t20ReportHeader">Switch</th><th class="t20ReportHeader">NE</th>
<th class="t20ReportHeader">port_card_slot</th>
<th class="t20ReportHeader">Vertical</th>
<th class="t20ReportHeader">Pillar</th>
<th class="t20ReportHeader">OUT CT Box</th>
<th class="t20ReportHeader">OUT Tag</th>
<th class="t20ReportHeader">IN CT Box</th>
<th class="t20ReportHeader">IN Tag</th>
<th class="t20ReportHeader">DP</th>
<th class="t20ReportHeader">DP Tag</th>
<th class="t20ReportHeader">DP Type</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="t20data">KKDPVLO01</td>
<td class="t20data">0003-02-117</td>
<td class="t20data">00</td>
<td class="t20data">1-001-01-013</td>
<td class="t20data">KKDPVL0062</td>
<td class="t20data">B2</td>
<td class="t20data">075</td>
<td class="t20data">A1</td>
<td class="t20data">013</td>
<td class="t20data">KKDPVL0062X0018</td>
<td class="t20data">004</td>
<td class="t20data">DP-DL</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

From VBA I am not able to access this.

By the way, I am using IE6 and I have to do this in IE6 only, and the above HTML code, I obtained from other system through Google chrome, using "Inspect".
But in IE6, I can only see "View Source" and here, it is not displaying the above generated HTML.

**Code:**

```
 Sub scrape()
        Dim ie As Object
        Dim baseurl As String
    
        Set ie = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
    
        With ie
            .navigate "http://itpc.sdc.bsnl.co.in:7777/pls/apex/f?p=204:1"
            .Visible = True
        End With
    
        Do While ie.Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop
    
        ie.document.getElementById("P101_USERNAME").Value = "b200800935"
        ie.document.getElementById("P101_PASSWORD").Value = "xxxxxxxx"
    
        Do While ie.Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop
    
        For Each l In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
            If l.className = "t20Button" Then
                l.Click
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    
        Do While ie.Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop
    
        'baseurl = Replace(ie.LocationUrl, "204", "124")
        'MsgBox ie.LocationUrl
        'MsgBox Replace(ie.LocationUrl, "204", "124") & "::NO::HOME_APP,HOME_PAGE:204,1"
    
        ie.navigate Replace(ie.LocationURL, "204", "124") & "::NO::HOME_APP,HOME_PAGE:204,1"
    
        Do While ie.Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop
    
        ie.document.getElementById("PHONE_NO").Value = "04565-282200"
        ie.document.getElementById("P1_GO").Click
    
        Do While ie.Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop
    
        For Each l In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
            If l.innerText = "04565-282200" Then
                l.Click
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    
        Do While ie.Busy
            DoEvents
        Loop
    
        ie.document.parentWindow.execScript "ajaxcall('CIRCUITS','CKT_LINK','CIRCUITS')"
    
        ' THE CODE IS OK UPTO THIS
        'THE ABOVE EXECUTION OF JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION CREATES A DYNAMIC TABLE IN WEB PAGE
        'WHICH IS NOT ACCESSIBLE IN VBA BY MY CODE
        ''ie.Quit
        ''Set ie = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Comment: Hmm, if you open the page inside the builtin browser ( Menu -> Data -> From web ) does the javascript run? If so, you can select the generated table there, and hence, macro those actions. We also use `CreateObject()` in VBA to create AJAX calls and JScript parsers to help us with these, but since you seem to be using very old software, I can't guarantee those exist in the versions you're using.

Comment: sure. I have added the code.

Comment: I have attached a image. There the fourth table titled "Circuit Details" is all i am concerned about. it is generated through the javascript code above.

Comment: Thanks. Can you also show the html where the event is attached ?

Comment: It would help to see the surrounding html. Have you checked it isn't nested in a Form/Frame/iFrame? Or if there is a not selectable indication? Or even different origin.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help. I actually got what i wanted by adding the following line of code. After the last line that executed the java script, I added the following line right after the execScript():

document.getElementbyId('div id name').innerHTML.

This 'div' was generated through the script, which was visible in the "View Source". Through this , I was able to access the table.
It returned a string containing the 'Table.../Table' portion within that 'div'. and i extracted the data through string manipulation. Don't know, how it worked, but i got what i want. Thank you all for your valuable suggestion.